# Need to understand following regular expression output

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python regular expression and going through python regular expression documentation. I am not able to comprehend the below code output - How 'c' got included as one of the groups. Below is the expression:

```
m = re.match("([abc])+", "abc")
print(m.groups())
print(m.group(1))
```

Output is:

```
('c',)
c
```

Comment: Do you mean `([abc]+)` as the regular expression? What do you expect?

Comment: Read: [Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with the greedy method of parsing regular expressions, in summary:

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

see https://regex101.com/r/ffBSOq/1